# program run with GNOME Alt-F2 dialog doesn't have focus

Tags: 11.04, window-manager, gnome, focus

I'm using GNOME 3 Shell on Ubuntu Natty (11.04). When I start a new program with Alt-F2, I'd like focus to be on that window. Instead, focus is given not to the previous window which had focus nor to the program I just ran, but to a *different* window.

Anyone have ideas on how to help the window manager give focus to the just-run program?

Comment: Strange, cannot repro anymore. I don't know what changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to have resolved on it's own

> Strange, cannot repro anymore. I don't know what changed.